# PHP secure way to store cookie data and compare to mysql entry?

Tags: mysql, cookies

I have a login system and I want people to be able to stay logged in. The way I am doing this is the following. When the user logs in and click "remember me" a cookie is created. The cookie has the following data.

```
email:::randomString
```

The ":::" is just a seperator between the email and string. An example would look like:

johndow@gmail.com:::EN8borW29qZMMJU8CNKivD91NFa3h5

The string is generated randomly and is not based on anything the user has inputted. The entire data is then encrypted using bcrypt and stored in a cookie.
An identical copy of the data on that cookie is then stored in a MySQL table entry. When the user loads a page during another session the cookie is read and decrypted. The table is then scanned for an identical copy that has that email and that string in it. If it is then the user is automatically logged in. I'm not sure if this is a secure way of doing this because of the following. Someone could copy the data from that cookie and create a new one on their PC with the exact data. When they load up the page the script reads their cookie and checks the database for a match which it will find and then log in the user.

How can I improve this method or have a new one altogether?

Comment: You may add IP address, or use some combination with cookie and local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add expiration field in your db table and check your incoming cookies against that so that you can re-new your cookie with another random value and force the attacker to attempt a new cookie steal or be blocked out,
2. Make your cookies http only,
3. Store browser-os info in your table and check your client requests against these and if not match ask to re-enter password (you do have a password field attached for every user, right?),
4. The previous step 3 implies a 'session' table so that we can follow who are logged and who not (I suspect a passwordless system from your description, not a good idea, so observing sessions is a necessity),
5. Enforce https protocol during login and thereafter.

Alternatively,
search for php login systems in github but expect to work a lot customizing it with your demands.

Lately, I did a lot of work to customize such a system which I didn't publish so far for reasons that have to do with business strategy but I assure you there is a LOT of work to build and secure such a system!

As a bonus I release just a functional diagram to comprehend the complexity I am talking about and the usefulness of even simple diagrams made from word processing software when we build software. It's sth that will save your life in the future!
[image]

Comment: when i store the cookie data in the table, should I also encrypt the random string in there or just in the clients cookie?

Comment: Well what's common in other libs: client sends the encrypted value, server decrypts it and compares it with the unencrypted value! I draw your attention to some redundancy: do we need critical info like email in a cookie? A table record should combine email with a unique value in cookie. Am I describing php's session system?

Comment: If you insist on writing critical info on client's side cause it throws db system out of equation (!) then play smart: search for "json web tokens", jwt.io, pick up a php lib (like it https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) and follow the official way to encrypt cookies between servers or between servers and clients!